# Can I create a Kafka topic with an ISR lower than the replication factor?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-platform

Meaning
rf =3 , byt Min.insyce.reaplica = 1, and When procuder setup ack=1, I want to make sure only need leader get data then cosnidering good.

However, I do see it comes with default even I setup it lower with the commmand. It shows automatically like this.

```
Topic:isr-set1  PartitionCount:6    ReplicationFactor:3 Configs:min.insync.replicas=1
    Topic: isr-set1 Partition: 0    Leader: 3   Replicas: 3,1,5 Isr: 3,1,5
    Topic: isr-set1 Partition: 1    Leader: 4   Replicas: 4,5,3 Isr: 4,5,3
    Topic: isr-set1 Partition: 2    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0,3,4 Isr: 0,3,4
    Topic: isr-set1 Partition: 3    Leader: 2   Replicas: 2,4,0 Isr: 2,4,0
```

I expect something like:

```
Topic:isr-set1  PartitionCount:6    ReplicationFactor:3 Configs:min.insync.replicas=1
    Topic: isr-set1 Partition: 0    Leader: 3   Replicas: 3,1,5 Isr: 3
    Topic: isr-set1 Partition: 1    Leader: 4   Replicas: 4,5,3 Isr: 4
    Topic: isr-set1 Partition: 2    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0,3,4 Isr: 0
    Topic: isr-set1 Partition: 3    Leader: 2   Replicas: 2,4,0 Isr: 2
```

Answer (score 4):

ISR means in sync replicas, It can equal or lower than replication factor, but you can not control it.

If you create a topic with `replication factor = 3`, that means Kafka keeps that topic-partition log in 3 different places. To keep in 3 different places, follower replicas need to get synced with leader replica for the partition. `In Sync Replicas` or `ISR` means this replica sync process. How many replicas are in synced with the leader.

But in your case you configured `Min ISR` to the one. That means when you produce data with `ack=all` it look in Kafka if there is atleast `min ISR` number of replicas are synced with the leader including leader. If not, it returns an error and not produced.

If you only need Leader availability, this `Min ISR` is not considered. ISR is also not considered in producing messages. So if you don't need replication (In sync replicas) just create topic with `replication factor = 1`. But it is too risky because there is no fault tolerance for that topic partitions.

> **[Replication](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#replication)**
>
> Kafka replicates the log for each topic's partitions across a
> configurable number of servers (you can set this replication factor on
> a topic-by-topic basis). This allows automatic failover to these
> replicas when a server in the cluster fails so messages remain
> available in the presence of failures.
>
> **[min.insync.replicas](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#topicconfigs_min.insync.replicas)**
>
> When a producer sets acks to "all" (or "-1"), this configuration
> specifies the minimum number of replicas that must acknowledge a write
> for the write to be considered successful. If this minimum cannot be
> met, then the producer will raise an exception (either
> NotEnoughReplicas or NotEnoughReplicasAfterAppend). When used
> together, min.insync.replicas and acks allow you to enforce greater
> durability guarantees. A typical scenario would be to create a topic
> with a replication factor of 3, set min.insync.replicas to 2, and
> produce with acks of "all". This will ensure that the producer raises
> an exception if a majority of replicas do not receive a write.

Comment: Yeah. I think whenever, a broker get bounce or temporaty dead, If ISR was showsing up 3, will become 2 broker on the list,meanwhile some underreplicate paritions will happen.
I seems no control on this list like you mentioned, Although I can setup ISR through config. 
This is intersting, if we cannot setup this, why kafka expose this to us at begining?

Comment: Bascialy, I just want to test, if say Ack=1, or all, when we have Min.ISR =1, then only leader ack is good enough, since if ISr=1, does not matter ack=1 or ack=all, it should be only 1 broker acked. The good reason for this is to avoid follower lag in some senarios. 
do you guys have work on this that prodcuer can still producing like this? @nipuna

Comment: And. for rf=1. That is of course not an option like you mentioned. I am trying to find a solution that can cover rf and isr both.